# Rails 6 - 'missing required keys: [:post_id]' when trying to render a 'comment' form directly on my posts#index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, blogs

I've been trying to build a facebook/blog type app where comments show directly under new posts, and you can also POST a new comment by rendering a form directly under the corresponding Post. As you'll learn in the rest of my post, I'm fairly new to Rails so any resources that directly help me understand the issue I'm having (even if it's just pointing me to the right parts of the Rails docs) would be super helpful.

As of right now, my homepage renders the post#index action, as well as a a post form so that you can create new posts directly on the index page. All of this works fine until I try to render my comment form. As a note, I'm only focusing on creating a new comment before implementing editing and deleting (not that that should affect anything I wouldn't think).

Unfortunately I keep getting this error -

[image]

Moreover, when I split each of these pages into a more traditional, `link_to XXXX_path` style where every form and action is on its own url page, everything works fine. I think there might be something fundamental that I'm just not understanding. So, before showing my code I'll just give a quick explanation of my understanding of how I expect things to work in my app

On the `index.html.erb` view:

1. Render the index page
2. Show each individual post and any corresponding info I want to display with my `each` method.
3. pass the specific instance of Post using `<%= render 'comment_form', :post => post %>`. This should also give me access to all of the params of said instance of post in my `_comment_form.html.erb` partial.

On the `_comment_form.html.erb` partial:

1. add `model: [post, @comment]` (as my comment controller is nested in post) so that Rails knows to build a new comment with the associated post instance that was pushed through my index view.

At the end of the day, if I had to guess, my issue is with my controllers - I feel like I've put the correct code in the methods/actions, but my hunch is that there's something conflicting between the `@post` instance variable and the `post` instance being iterated over in my `each` method. I'm really not sure what the problem is and any help would be much appreciated. I hope I didn't over (or under) explain my problem. Thanks for the help in advance!

**views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<nav>
</nav>

<h1>Posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <%= render 'form' %>

  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to post.user.email, user_path(post.user_id) %></td>
        <td><%= post.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <%= render 'comment_form', :post => post %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

**views/posts/_comment_form.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= form_with(model: [post, @comment], url: post_comments_path, method: "post", local: true) do |form| %>
  

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  Please sign in to comment on the post!
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  #before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @post = post_exists?
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to index, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:body)
    end

    def post_exists?
      current_user.posts.build if current_user != nil
    end
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build
  end
  
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comments_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :posts do
     resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
  
  resources :users
  root to: 'posts#index'
```

**Models**

```
>user.rb
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

>post.rb
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

>comment.rb
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
```

Comment: ` <%= form_with(model: [post, @comment]` probably should be ` <%= form_with(model: [@post, @comment]`. The error states there is no post id, which means the value you supplied for the post is nil -- either because the wrong variable was used or the post wasn't loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried this but still run into the exact same error. It's almost like my form just isn't able to directly interact with my post params whether it's through the controller or the form itself.

Comment: it's likely the controller doesn't have the proper context and isn't loading the post.  What's the url you are generating for the comment form?

Comment: I hope this answers your question, but here is my routes for my generating and posting comments. I tried to format this comment so it doesn't suck to look at but it seems impossible from this aha.

(post_comments  POST  /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)   comments#create)
(new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)  comments#new)

Comment: Always best to edit the question with useful information.

Comment: Where are you setting `@comment` that you are using in your `_comment_form.html.erb` file?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @dbugger, I'll make sure to put relevant info directly in the post next time. The answer below solved it so I'm good to go. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it is missing the post_id on line 2 in your comment_form.
You got:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: [post, @comment], url: post_comments_path, method: "post", local: true) do |form| %>
```

The url is set to post_comments_path but it doesn't knows which post so you need to pass the post to it as an argument like so:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: [post, @comment], url: post_comments_path(post), method: "post", local: true) do |form| %>
```

Although this will probably solve the current error, you will hit another error since you also got @comment in the comment_form and in your posts#index you don't declare @comment. You also can't declare @comment because it is depending on the post. You could try to solve that with:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: [post, post.comments.new], url: post_comments_path, method: "post", local: true) do |form| %>
```

Comment: Amazing this solved it, thanks! I didn't even think to pass the post argument to my url path. I'll make sure to keep that in mind from now on.